# Download pdf in localhost

Tags: html, pdf

I am making a website on my localhost and I have a download pdf button in the footer. When I try to download it it pops up in Chrome downloads but itsays it failed to download. When i go to the URL of the pdf it says CANNOT GET /images/.pdf so I think its a localhost problem? If i go see the url of an image in the same folder it works but the pdf doesnt work.

[image]

This is my code in JADE

```
li.
                <a href='http://www.bpost.be/site/nl/disclaimer.html'>Disclaimer</a> 
                |
                <a href='/Reglement-SurpriseWebshop-NL.pdf' download>Wedstrijdreglement</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="./directory/yourfile.pdf" download>Download the pdf</a>
```

Try this